# Evaluate $(-\iota e)^{2+\iota 2}$ using a branch of logarithm with a branch cut $\alpha = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Evaluate $(-\iota  e)^{2+\iota 2}$ using a branch of logarithm with a branch cut $\alpha = 0$

**My Attempt:**

We know $- \iota = e^{\iota \frac{-\pi}{2}}$.

$(-\iota  e)^{2+\iota 2} = (e^{\iota \frac{-\pi}{2}+1} )^{2+2 \iota}= e^{2- \iota \pi +\pi +2i}= e^{2 +\pi +2i - i \pi}=e^{2 +\pi}(\cos (-\pi + 2) + i \sin (-\pi + 2))$

Can you please let me know where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: Is $\iota$ the imaginary unit? If yes, $-i\neq e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Comment: Yess....Sorry ..Let me edit.

Comment: Is it okay now ? @vitamind

Comment: How do you know you’re wrong?

Comment: I have not used that logarithm thing anywhere.@Tavish

Comment: Please let me know if there is any error ?@Tavish

Comment: Can you please tell me if there is any error ?@vitamind

Comment: There's no such thing as "a branch of logarithm with a branch cut $\alpha=0$". If you want to specify a branch of $\log$, you need to give a branch point and an angle. Also, that should be 'i' the English letter, not the Greek iota ($\iota$).